# Is there a sutta which answers where a nirvanaised consciousnesses is after death and comapres it to a fire going out?

Tags: reference-request, sutras, nirvana, canon, final-nirvana

Is there a sutta which answers where a nirvanaised consciousnesses is after death and comapres it to a fire going out?

I thought there was, but can't find it. Sounds like [Vacchagota](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn44/sn44.008.than.html) mashed up with the [fire sermon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_Sermon).

I'm asking because I like the image, and it almost appears in some modernist poetry.

Failing a sutta, any zen discourses.

Failing that, anywhere in the canon.

Failing that, any important Buddhist, living or dead.

Failing that an academic.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably thinking of [Itivuttaka 44](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/iti/iti.2.028-049.than.html#iti-044):

> This was said by the Blessed One, said by the Arahant, so I have
>   heard: "Monks, there are these two forms of the Unbinding property.
>   Which two? The Unbinding property with fuel remaining, & the Unbinding
>   property with no fuel remaining.
>
> And what is the Unbinding property with fuel remaining? There is the
>   case where a monk is an arahant whose fermentations have ended, who
>   has reached fulfillment, finished the task, laid down the burden,
>   attained the true goal, ended the fetter of becoming, and is released
>   through right gnosis. His five sense faculties still remain and, owing
>   to their being intact, he is cognizant of the agreeable & the
>   disagreeable, and is sensitive to pleasure & pain. His ending of
>   passion, aversion, & delusion is termed the Unbinding property with
>   fuel remaining. (Note1)
>
> And what is the Unbinding property with no fuel remaining? There is
>   the case where a monk is an arahant whose fermentations have ended,
>   who has reached fulfillment, finished the task, laid down the burden,
>   attained the true goal, ended the fetter of becoming, and is released
>   through right gnosis. For him, all that is sensed, being unrelished,
>   will grow cold right here. This is termed the Unbinding property with
>   no fuel remaining." (Note2)
>
> **Note1 and Note2 (commentary by Thanissaro Bhikkhu):**
>   With fuel remaining (*sa-upadisesa*) and with no fuel
>   remaining (*anupadisesa*): The analogy here is to a fire. In the first
>   case, the flames are out, but the embers are still glowing. In the
>   second, the fire is so thoroughly out that the embers have grown cold.
>   The "fuel" here is the [five aggregates](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/study/khandha.html). While the arahant is still
>   alive, he/she still experiences the five aggregates, but they do not
>   burn with the fires of passion, aversion, or delusion. When the
>   arahant passes away, there is no longer any experience of aggregates
>   here or anywhere else.